# Initializing virtual inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, virtual-inheritance

Consider the following virtual inheritance hierarchy

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct base
{
  base() = default;
  base( std::string const& s ) : s_(s) {}

  std::string print() { return s_; }

private:
  std::string s_;
};

struct derived : virtual base
{
  derived( std::string const& s ) : base( "cool formatting: " + s ) {}
};

struct more_derived : virtual derived
{
  more_derived( std::string const& s ) : derived( "even cooler formatting: " + s ) {}
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << more_derived( "foo" ).print() << std::endl;
}
```

Desired output:

```
cool formatting: even cooler formatting: foo
```

The code doesn't print anything because `more_derived` is not explicitly calling the `base` constructor that takes a string, and so the default `base` constructor is called. Moreover, due to `virtual` inheritance `derived`'s initialization of `base` is ignored.

How can I get the desired output while maintaining virtual inheritance and not having to call each base class constructor explicitly?

**EDIT:**
I realize what I'm asking for is not possible using constructor calls down the inheritance hierarchy because of virtual inheritance. I was hoping someone could provide an alternate method that would produce the desired result upon construction of `most_derived`.

Comment: This would fail to compile if it weren't for `base() = default;`. With virtual inheritance, the most derived type **must** call any virtual base constructors; here it's done implicitly (from `more_derived`'s constructor) with `base`'s default constructor.

Comment: @ildjarn I realize that. If what I am asking for were possible I'd get rid of the defaulted constructor.

Comment: @Prætorian: The default constructor is unrelated to the rest, you can still call the constructor that takes a string from the most derived type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for two contradictory goals. On one side you want to maintain virtual inheritance (do you really need it?) and on the other side you want the constructor not to be called from the most derived type directly.

You cannot get both, so pick one. You can of course pass the *desired* string from the most derived type, but I am guessing that the point is not the actual value, but the fact that the value is constructed from the bottom up...

Comment: This isn't to solve any real problem, I was playing with virtual inheritance. You're right, I could just call the `base` constructor with the desired string from `more_derived` (assuming `derived` has a default constructor) but that's not the point. I would like to have the calls be passed down the inheritance hierarchy. Please see the edit I made.

Comment: @Prætorian: That cannot be done. To quote from the deleted answer from Dietmar: *When you use virtual inheritance, the most derived class decides what the constructor parameters should be the virtual bases. The reason for this is that you expect that a most derived class actually contains multiple paths from the most derived to the base class. Otherwise, you wouldn't use virtual inheritance. In this case, neither of the the intermediate bases would have the better constructor argument for the base.* Note the key point: if you are using virtual inheritance, the expectation is multiple paths.

Comment: Hmm, that *multiple paths to base* explanation is the best I've ever heard for explaining the thought process behind virtual inheritance. Would you mind weighing in on [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/c70f738495a298501a414ce0001863b0)? Two phase construction seems to get the job done. But I think all of this really makes it clear that virtual inheritance is only applicable in very specific cases.

Comment: @Prætorian: The first thing is that LWS is broken and blurry in Safari, but I guess that is not the question. Actually I don't quite know what the question is, that is, I don't see the point of that exercise. Note that you cannot do that to generate the string that is passed to the `base` constructor (You could rework that into static functions to get the desired effect, assuming that the string does not use other members of the objects). But again, I don't see the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: I guess the the biggest problem here is that I'm not trying to solve any real problem. This question came about as a result of tinkering with virtual inheritance. LWS kept crashing Firefox 15 Beta, but it works well on 16 Beta, hopefully Safari will get fixed soon too. Anyway, thanks for your answer and comments.